# How do I authorize one Azure Active Directory app to access a different AAD App Service Web API using a Bearer token?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I've been searching for a couple days, and I can't seem to find a straightforward guide on how to set up Authorization (AuthZ) between an AAD App and my AAD Web API set up in App Service. I've tried things like [this official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad), but I can't seem to get calls with a Bearer token from the client app to work.

Has anyone done this successfully? Is there a step by step guide out there that could help?

Please let me know if there are any questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement your requirements, you need to expose an api in your AAD Web API first.
[image]

Then go to your AAD App which used to request the token, add the permission to it.
[image]

[image]

Click "Grant admin consent for *" button.
[image]

After that, we can request the access token successfully (below I provide a sample use [password flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) for your reference)
[image]

In your Web API app, you need to parse the access token and get the scope permission from the access token. And then determine whether the request has permission.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough guide! Is this possible with the App Service AAD settings in my linked tutorial? Or do I need to turn that off and do all of the AuthZ in my code?

Comment: Hi @justindao You can do registering your app to ad by following the steps in your linked tutorial. But I think we need to parse the access token just in the code.